# Вопрос связанный с датой

Tags: python, datetime

Пользователь берет кредит под ставку 5% в час. И естественно каждый час он будет должен на 5% больше. Когда кредит взят мы должны записать дату и время, а потом когда пользователь захочет оплатить кредит мы сравниваем дату и время которое сейчас и что было на момент взятия. Так вот как это сделать на Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить текущую дату и время можно с помощью модуля [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

Даты можно вычитать друг из друга, при этом будет возвращён объект [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), который будет хранить разницу в секундах между датами. На основе разницы в секундах можно посчитать и разницу в часах (нацело поделив на 3600).

Повышение суммы долга на 5% каждый час — это [геометрическая прогрессия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F). Вам необходимо найти `n`-ный член этой прогрессии.

***Пример:***

```py
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

# Support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic
money = Decimal(100)
rate = Decimal('1.05')

start = datetime.now()
# 5 hours later...
end = datetime.now()

hours = Decimal((end - start).total_seconds()) // 3600
duty = money * rate**(hours)

print(duty)
```

***stdout:***

```py
127.6281562500
```

Comment: Только нужно [total_seconds()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) брать от timedelta, просто seconds вернет количество секунд, которое идет свыше целых суток: `timedelta(seconds=24*3600+1).seconds == 1`

Comment: @insolor Спасибо большое за замечание. Исправил <3